# Problem with Roscopter (Arducopter interface for ros)

Tags: ros, mavlink

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone i am new to this group and ROS, and i am writing because I have a problem with the interface for the ROS arducopter and also wanted to better understand the things that I am not clear on this subject.

I'm writing my graduation thesis, and I'm working on quadrorotor automated using the ROS, in the beginning I focused on Parrot AR.Drone 2.0, but now now I'm focused dell'arducopter.

My setup is Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Fuerte, I own an AR.Drone 2.0 but NOT own a arducopter.

The first problem is with the interface roscopter, I followed all the instructions on code.google.com/p/roscopter/

but when I go to run the command:

nodes / roscopter.py - device = / dev/ttyUSB1 - rate = 57600 - enable-control = true

I get the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "nodes / roscopter.py", line 7, in 
import roscopter.msg
File "/ home / joe / fuerte_workspace / roscopter / nodes / roscopter.py", line 7, in 
import roscopter.msg
ImportError: No module named msg

The error is in the import roscopter.msg, and in fact inside the folder there is no msg file "roscopert.msg" I have to define it? in what way? how?

The second problem is that I have to figure out which topic should I write in order to execute the commands of TakeOff, Land, various movements etc ... For example, with the 2.0 ardrone to make a takeoff was enough to send a message "std_msgs / Empty" on the topic "/ ardrone / takeoff" with the command on the terminal of ubuntu: rostopic pub -1 / ardrone / takeoff std_msgs / Empty How does works for the roscopter?

Another thing that i want to figure is the role of MAVLink, and how does works .

Thank you very much in advance and sorry for my English

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62455/problem-with-roscopter-(arducopter-interface-for-ros)/) by [Giona Grancheli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4854/giona-grancheli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds to me like you didn't quite get the package built correctly.  Inside of the roscopter_base/msg/ directory, you will find all of roscopter message definitions.  If `rosmake` successfully builds the project, it should create a roscopter_base/msg_gen/ directory, and a roscopter_base/src/roscopter/ directory.  These directories actually have the necessary code to use the messages in `roscpp` and `rospy`.  If you don't have those directories (or the files that are supposed to be in them), you will encounter the error that you are seeing.  Try running

```
rosmake roscopter
```

to (re)generate the necessary files.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0